# Best Practice for overriding a small portion of code in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, coding-style

I would like to override a function in a given class and I am looking for the most elegant way. Let's say I have a class `Foo` with the function `bar()`. I only want to change the last line of `bar`. More specifically I would like to change the `step()` function in the `Adam` class of `torch.optim` in PyTorch.

Is the only way of doing this, by creating a subclass and overriding `bar`. I would need to copy all the duplicate code to just change one single line. Is there a better way?

Here are the actual implementation. The upper one is the original function and the bottom one (which is the name besides the very last line) is my custom one:

```py
def step(self, closure=None):
    """Performs a single optimization step.

    Arguments:
        closure (callable, optional): A closure that reevaluates the model
            and returns the loss.
    """
    loss = None
    if closure is not None:
        loss = closure()

    for group in self.param_groups:
        for p in group['params']:
            if p.grad is None:
                continue
            grad = p.grad.data
            if grad.is_sparse:
                raise RuntimeError('Adam does not support sparse gradients, please consider SparseAdam instead')
            amsgrad = group['amsgrad']

            state = self.state[p]

            # State initialization
            if len(state) == 0:
                state['step'] = 0
                # Exponential moving average of gradient values
                state['exp_avg'] = torch.zeros_like(p.data)
                # Exponential moving average of squared gradient values
                state['exp_avg_sq'] = torch.zeros_like(p.data)
                if amsgrad:
                    # Maintains max of all exp. moving avg. of sq. grad. values
                    state['max_exp_avg_sq'] = torch.zeros_like(p.data)

            exp_avg, exp_avg_sq = state['exp_avg'], state['exp_avg_sq']
            if amsgrad:
                max_exp_avg_sq = state['max_exp_avg_sq']
            beta1, beta2 = group['betas']

            state['step'] += 1

            if group['weight_decay'] != 0:
                grad.add_(group['weight_decay'], p.data)

            # Decay the first and second moment running average coefficient
            exp_avg.mul_(beta1).add_(1 - beta1, grad)
            exp_avg_sq.mul_(beta2).addcmul_(1 - beta2, grad, grad)
            if amsgrad:
                # Maintains the maximum of all 2nd moment running avg. till now
                torch.max(max_exp_avg_sq, exp_avg_sq, out=max_exp_avg_sq)
                # Use the max. for normalizing running avg. of gradient
                denom = max_exp_avg_sq.sqrt().add_(group['eps'])
            else:
                denom = exp_avg_sq.sqrt().add_(group['eps'])

            bias_correction1 = 1 - beta1 ** state['step']
            bias_correction2 = 1 - beta2 ** state['step']
            step_size = group['lr'] * math.sqrt(bias_correction2) / bias_correction1

            p.data.addcdiv_(-step_size, exp_avg, denom)

    return loss
```

```py
def step(self, closure=None):
    """Performs a single optimization step.

    Arguments:
        closure (callable, optional): A closure that reevaluates the model
            and returns the loss.
    """
    loss = None
    if closure is not None:
        loss = closure()

    for group in self.param_groups:
        for p in group['params']:
            if p.grad is None:
                continue
            grad = p.grad.data
            if grad.is_sparse:
                raise RuntimeError('Adam does not support sparse gradients, please consider SparseAdam instead')
            amsgrad = group['amsgrad']

            state = self.state[p]

            # State initialization
            if len(state) == 0:
                state['step'] = 0
                # Exponential moving average of gradient values
                state['exp_avg'] = torch.zeros_like(p.data)
                # Exponential moving average of squared gradient values
                state['exp_avg_sq'] = torch.zeros_like(p.data)
                if amsgrad:
                    # Maintains max of all exp. moving avg. of sq. grad. values
                    state['max_exp_avg_sq'] = torch.zeros_like(p.data)

            exp_avg, exp_avg_sq = state['exp_avg'], state['exp_avg_sq']
            if amsgrad:
                max_exp_avg_sq = state['max_exp_avg_sq']
            beta1, beta2 = group['betas']

            state['step'] += 1

            if group['weight_decay'] != 0:
                grad.add_(group['weight_decay'], p.data)

            # Decay the first and second moment running average coefficient
            exp_avg.mul_(beta1).add_(1 - beta1, grad)
            exp_avg_sq.mul_(beta2).addcmul_(1 - beta2, grad, grad)
            if amsgrad:
                # Maintains the maximum of all 2nd moment running avg. till now
                torch.max(max_exp_avg_sq, exp_avg_sq, out=max_exp_avg_sq)
                # Use the max. for normalizing running avg. of gradient
                denom = max_exp_avg_sq.sqrt().add_(group['eps'])
            else:
                denom = exp_avg_sq.sqrt().add_(group['eps'])

            bias_correction1 = 1 - beta1 ** state['step']
            bias_correction2 = 1 - beta2 ** state['step']
            step_size = group['lr'] * math.sqrt(bias_correction2) / bias_correction1

            # Changed p.data.addcdiv_(-step_size, exp_avg, denom) to
            p.data.add_(-step_size * (exp_avg / denom))

    return loss
```

Comment: It would help if you gave a more realistic example, both for the return statements, and some actual code instead of a comment saying "a bunch of code". Surely there is *some* logical relation between the two parts of the method? Otherwise make them two methods, and if necessary, make a convenience method which calls both of them.

Comment: because the original code is rather long I thought it was pretty unnecessary to include it, but I edited in as you said.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the original code, just a sufficient example to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Is the first method one that you can edit, or just the subclass?

Comment: Sorry, I included it now. The first method is the original function from the class I can't edit as it is a function in PyTorch's `Adam` class. The second block of code is the overwritten method

Comment: Ah. I suspect there is no good solution to your problem. The only alternative I can think of is to go through the data structure and monkey-patch the `addcdiv_` methods on all of the relevant objects. But that's not a good thing to do, so duplicating the code is probably the right thing to do here. Maybe someone else can think of something?

Comment: Ok thank you. Unfortunately, I thought the same. Thanks for the clarification